# Web приложение без использования JSP

Tags: java, java-ee

Изучаю сервлеты. По заданию необходимо написать веб-приложение, которое умеет добавлять, изменять, удалять и отображать данные таблицы. При этом JSP использовать нельзя. В интернете куча примеров с использованием JSP. Вопрос возможно глупый, но тем не менее буду признателен за развернутый ответ: можно ли написать веб-приложение БЕЗ использования JSP - только сервлет. Если да, то можно ли получить ссылку на пример именно такой реализации задачи?

Comment: Конечно, можно, Таких примеров полно - просто берете ссылку на writer из HttpServletResponse и пишете в него html. [Вот подробный гайд от оракла](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafv.html#bnafz).

Comment: спасибо, ещё такой вопрос, а как можно отправить форму, т.е. допустим ввести логин и пароль, далее по нажатию кнопки отправить в сервлет эти данные для последующего занесения их в БД?

Comment: Непонятна формулировка вопроса: что означает "как отправить форму"? Браузер ее сам отправит. Вам надо создать HTML файл с формой - это статический контент, поэтому отдавать его через сервлет необязательно, и потом обработать полученные от формы данные в сервлете.

Comment: немного не ясно выразил суть вопроса, простите, у меня уже есть html форма с полями для ввода значений, и есть кнопка sumbit, интересует как именно по нажатию этой кнопки извлечь эти значение и уже поместить в sql базу, т.е. грубо говоря как создать взаимодействие между html формой (веб - приложением) и DAO (которое работает с таблицами), именно такого плана пример я и просил выше, вот пример той реализации которая мне необходима, правда тут с jsp, [ссылка] (https://danielniko.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simple-crud-using-jsp-servlet-and-mysql/), необходимо что то подобное без использование jsp.

Comment: Получаете в сервлете параметры из запроса ч/з метод `getParameter()` и записываете их в БД. [Вот пример](http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/registration-form-example-in-servlet.php), не стесняйтесь пользоваться гуглом.